# Ajax fires twice replacing last requests content in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have looked at other questions relating to this and it seems I need to wait for the first Ajax request to finish before carrying on with the next. I thought that the code below would do that but for some reason the request fires twice.

```
function infiniteScroll() {
  if($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
      //Bail out right away if we're busy loading the next chunk
      if(window.pagination_loading){
        return;
      }
      var more_url = $('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href');
        if(more_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50){
          //Make a note that we're busy loading the next chunk.
          window.pagination_loading = true;
          $('.pagination').html('<img src="/assets/ajax_loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />')
          $.getScript(more_url).always(function(){
          window.pagination_loading = false;
        });
      }
    });
  } 
}
```

js.erb file

```
$('#all_images').append("<%= j render 'shared/image_ajax' %>");
console.log('script fired');
<% if @images.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @images %>');
<% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').empty();
<% end %>
```

So when I scroll down the page (real slow aswell just to capture the event) i get this in my console

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/portfolio?page=2&_=1456333727211"
script fired
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/portfolio?_=1456333727212&page=3"
script fired
```

Am I not dealing with this correctly or can anyone see any potential issues here?

### Update

This is an example of the markup that is generated when making the first scroll

So when the page loads 4 results are shown

```
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 PlacesOfInterest" id="image_18" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 PlacesOfInterest" id="image_17" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 Landscapes" id="image_16" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 Landscapes" id="image_15" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
```

Then I scroll and another 4 results get appended

```
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 PlacesOfInterest" id="image_18" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 PlacesOfInterest" id="image_17" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 Landscapes" id="image_16" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 Landscapes" id="image_15" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 PlacesOfInterest" id="image_14" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 PlacesOfInterest" id="image_13" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 PlacesOfInterest Landscapes" id="image_12" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-12 ok-sd-6 PlacesOfInterest Landscapes" id="image_11" style="position: absolute; left: 24.9593%; top: 0px;">...</div>
```

However as a user I only see 4 images (the 4 just appended replace the first 4 loaded), after this though the scroll event works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `$.active` returns 0; if it does, the first ajax request was completed.

So in your case:

```
if ($.active !== 0) {
  return;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also try the `$.ajaxStop()`

More details here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm afraid that doesn't help, I've added an example of the markup that is generated when I make the first scroll